# How to compute the Time In and Time Out and get to labels

Tags: c#

How can i calculate the existing time in my label and add them each other ?

I want that for my simple payroll but im confuse to the codes.

```
public void computeTimeInAndOut()
{
    TimeSpan t1 = new TimeSpan();
    TimeSpan.TryParse(label2.Text, out t1);
    TimeSpan t2 = new TimeSpan();
    TimeSpan.TryParse(label6.Text, out t2);
    TimeSpan t3 = t1.Add(t2);
    label7.Text = t3.ToString();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just do exactly what you did

```
TimeSpan t;
TimeSpan t2;
TimeSpan.TryParse(label2.Text.Replace(" PM", ""), out t);
TimeSpan.TryParse(label6.Text.Replace(" PM", ""), out t2);
TimeSpan @new = t.Add(t2);
label7.Text = @new.ToString();
```

Comment: still 0 value sir :( @cc24

Comment: @Strudops yep sorry missed something. I've edited my anwser the new version works.